# RStudio Crashed when Executing rbf method

Tags: r, rstudio, r-caret

I don't know what may be the crash cause.. this occurs when I train `rbf` method with `Caret`, like this:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
library(dplyr)
data("HouseVotes84")
dummy_data_classif <- HouseVotes84[,1:length(colnames(HouseVotes84))] %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.numeric)

resampling <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                               number = 5,
                               allowParallel = FALSE) 
model <- caret::train(Class ~ ., 
                      data = dummy_data_classif, 
                      method = "rbf", 
                      trControl = resampling)
```

In the contrary, The Original `rbf` from `RSNNS` execution working fine as Expected:

```
library(RSNNS)
inputs <- as.matrix(dummy_data_classif[,-1])
outputs <- as.matrix(as.numeric(dummy_data_classif[,1]))
model <- RSNNS::rbf(inputs, outputs, size=40, maxit=1000, 
                    initFuncParams=c(0, 1, 0, 0.01, 0.01), 
                    learnFuncParams=c(1e-8, 0, 1e-8, 0.1, 0.8), linOut=TRUE)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "RStudio Crashed"?

Comment: Sorry, What I mean is after the code executed, the RSession Crashed and need to be restarted again

Comment: Sounds like a bug in RStudio itself. Ideally their error-handling should be able to handle any buggy code you run. My evidence-free guess is that this package invokes some underlying C/C++ code which has some memory management issues.

Comment: I see, maybe then I will try to inform this to the RStudio community too

Comment: Where does `HouseVotes84` come from?

Comment: @Phil the HouseVotes84 dataset is from mlbench package

Comment: I would file an issue on their GH repo